# Excel Conditional Formatting Based on Column Header and Cell Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I am trying to highlight cells that contain values over 500, but ONLY in columns that have "Variance" in the column header. Is there a way to do this? I know you can highlight specific columns using something like =$A1="Variance" but not sure how to write the formula to include only highlight the cells in those specific columns with values over 500.

Comment: `=AND(A$1="Variance",A2>500)` and apply to the columns in question, excluding the headers.

Comment: ^^ Or, include the headers and use `=AND(A$1="Variance",ISNUMBER(A1),A1>500)`

Comment: thanks all, does this work if the header contains "variance" but does not start with the word? I tried using wildcards but no luck.

Comment: @arisophia, Use `NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Variance",A$1)))`. ie. `=AND(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Variance",A$1))),ISNUMBER(A1),A1>500)`